# Is it okay to use a combination of letters and numbers as a primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I need to create a new table relating customers, regions, sites, and sales managers all together. I am relatively new to SQL and have an idea of creating an abstract 'meaningless' customer ID in order to be the primary key across all this data. However, the company I work for already has a 'customer number' which consists of a mix of letters and numbers, for example a customer number could be : A0123.

My question is: is this good enough to be a primary key across the data table which I am trying to create?

Comment: FYI: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key versus https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification! I need to study more about data theory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: is this good enough to be a primary key across the data table which I am trying to create?

**Short answer, yes, as long as they're unique.** I've worked in production systems that had several tables linked using a Primary Key that is an alphanumeric 'String/Char' ('a mix of letters and numbers', as you said).

Long answer: it depends. For performance reasons, you would ideally prefer using Integer/Big Integer for your primary key IF YOU HAVE A CHOICE (often you don't - some primary keys simply can not be integers, because they are not numeric in nature!)

If the 'customer number' can be restricted to a certain size - say 10/20/100 characters - then certainly there should be no issue with using String/Char datatype. For example, in mysql you can use the datatype `CHAR(10)` if you know that your primary key will contain <= 10 characters.

*The performance risk only exists if you are completely unsure how long each 'customer number' will be (and your tables are LARGE) and you use a 'lenient' datatype without restricting its size* (e.g. CHAR instead of CHAR(10))

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! The key will not be longer than 100 characters and may even be less than 10, this shouldn't result in a performance issue right?

Comment: Yes, you should be good with regards to performance issues. I recommend `VARCHAR`, since the 'Customer Number' seems to be a variable length. Something like `VARCHAR(255)` where 255 is the max number of bytes (usually max number of characters) should be good. Take a look at this table here if you want a little comparsion between char and varchar: 
[The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html)